# How Do I Listen To And React To JavaScript Events In Shopware 6 Storefront

Tags: javascript, plugins, shopware6

I am building a Shopware 6 JavaScript plugin for the storefront. I created a button and need to listen to it and react accordingly when it is 'Clicked'.

Below is my code which does not seem to work.

**main.js file code below**

```js
//Resources\app\storefront\src\main.js

import TestClickPlugin from './testclick/testclick.plugin';

const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
PluginManager.register('TestClickPlugin', TestClickPlugin, '.swp');
```

**plugin file code below**

```js
//Resources\app\storefront\src\testclick\testclick.plugin.js
import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';

export default class TemporaryWatermarkPlugin extends Plugin {

    init() {

       document.querySelector(".swp").addEventListener("click",  this.logThis().bind(this));       
    }

    logThis() {
        console.log("It Works!!!!!");     
    }
   
}
```

**And lastly, my twig file code below**

```
//Resources\views\storefront\page\product-detail\buy-widget.html.twig

{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget.html.twig' %}

    {% block page_product_detail_buy_inner %}

        {{ parent() }}


            {% block swp_block %}

                <div>
                   <button class="swp">Click Me </button>
                </div>

            {% endblock %}

    {% endblock %}
```

How do I get the function `logThis()` to run when clicked in the storefront.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```js
this.logThis().bind(this)
```

to

```js
this.logThis.bind(this)
```

since you want to reference the function, not call it.

Also in the `init` function you may want to use `this.el` instead of `document.querySelector(".swp")` since you already registered the plugin for that element.